# html2canvas will not capture image inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

i have a little problem how can i capture an image inside a div with htmls2canvas. i want to upload images inside a div and write text inside div but when i try to convert my div to image i can only see the text and not the image inside the div. how can i allow html2canvas to capture the images that have been uploaded? or is their another code for capturing images besides htmls2canvas.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 
var element = $("#firstshirt"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable
 
    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

 $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^torcdesign.com:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "<?php echo $confirm_coded ?>").attr("href", newData);
 });

});
```